# How can I allow HTML in a whitelist with PHP

Tags: php, filter, sanitization

I know there is a lot of discussion for years on best methods of filtering data with PHP but I would like to go the whitelist approach in my current project.

I only want a user to be able to use the following HTML

```
<b>bold</b>
<i>italics</i>
<u>underline</u>
<s>strikethrough</s>
<big>Big size</big >
<small>Small size</small>

Hyperlink <a href="http://www.site.com">website</a>

A Bulleted List:
<ul>
<li>One Item</li>
<li>Another Item</li>
</ul>

An Ordered List:
<ol>
<li> First Item</li>
<li> Second Item</li>
</ol>

<blockquote>Because it is indented</blockquote>

<h1>Heading 1</h1>
<h2>Heading 2</h2>
<h3>Heading 3</h3>
```

Can anyone show me the best method of doing this for performance in PHP?  I have only in the past allowed all html minus certain codes

Comment: On a side note you should use <strong> instead of <b> because <b> is not valid html.

Comment: `<b>` is valid HTML. It is not deprecated. It is not removed. (Although some people think it should be). Bold text is a form of presentation and is not the same as strong emphasis. You shouldn't simply replace any instance of `<b>` with `<strong>`, you should consider what semantics are correct for the specific situation and use whatever is best (which might be something that isn't `<strong>` combined with CSS `font-weight`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution would be `strip_tags(),` which accepts a second argument containing allowable tags:

```
strip_tags($string, "<b><i><u><a><s><big><small><ul><li><ol><blockquote><h1><h2><h3>");
```

Comment: It's no good. strip_tags is a simplistic approach to a difficult problem, which has always had many workarounds to get bad content in. Even if it were bug-free, the lack of attribute filtering leaves you no way to disallow harmful constructs like `<a onmouseover="do_script_injection">`.

Answer (score 8):

I believe the **HTML Purifier Library** will work nicely:

**http://htmlpurifier.org/**

> HTML Purifier is a standards-compliant
>   HTML filter library written in PHP.
>   HTML Purifier will not only remove all
>   malicious code (better known as XSS)
>   with a thoroughly audited, secure yet
>   permissive whitelist, it will also
>   make sure your documents are standards
>   compliant, something only achievable
>   with a comprehensive knowledge of
>   W3C's specifications. Tired of using
>   BBCode due to the current landscape of
>   deficient or insecure HTML filters?
>   Have a WYSIWYG editor but never been
>   able to use it? Looking for
>   high-quality, standards-compliant,
>   open-source components for that
>   application you're building? HTML
>   Purifier is for you!

Comment: this is nice but very very bulky, in fact it's HUGE

Comment: Well yes, filtering HTML is actually a very hard job.

Answer (score 1):

Another route is using strip_tags with the second argument.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

Answer (score 1):

I would run the submitted code through tidy to normalize it first, and then use xpath or apply xslt to only select allowed elements. This way, *nothing* can leak. Do bear in mind, too, that in any given website situation you would probably have thousands if not hundreds of thousands of read requests for every write request [that uses tidy and xpath/xslt] so on average the performance impact is negligible. If you are doing batch processing on the other hand..

Edit: oh and: **DON'T** do this with regular expressions. It is mathematically impossible to do it correctly.