# Javascript injection

Tags: php, javascript, code-injection

I need to solve a problem with javascript injection in a form textarea and fields

```
script type='text/javascript'
window.location='http:site.com';
```

/script

or

```
a href='javascript:...'
```

or

form action...

or

```
input name...
```

but i preserve some html tags for example a, b, ul... is this possible?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1975613/how-can-i-allow-html-in-a-whitelist-with-php (and ignore the accepted answer (which currently as a score of zero) in favour of the one about HTML purifier).

Answer (score 1):

Try using [HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/) to specify just what types of HTML you want to allow to protect yourself from such XSS attacks.

Answer (score -1):

If you're worried about XSS, you need to process the input on the server side to make sure there's no JavaScript in it. Hopefully this Perl example will help (apologies for the regex, it's not my strong suit)

```
use strict;
my $str = <<HTML;
<body>
        <div>
                sfdasfasdfs
                <script type="text/javascript">
                        window.location.href = "http://badsite.com";
                </script>
                sadfssdfssdf
        </div>
</body>
HTML

$str =~ s/<script.*?>[\s\w\d\W]*<\/script>//g;

print "$str\n";
```

Comment: This won't strip out most of the examples given in the question. Nor, for that matter, would it strip out `<SCRIPT>`! Use an HTML parser to parse HTML. Writing sufficient regular expressions to make a piece of HTML safe is very difficult (and will end up with a lot of code).